# Slow update on GTT(Global temp table) in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, oracle11g, database-performance

I am using global temp table to capture session specific data in Oracle. I have insert and update on this table.

It was working fine with a single user logging to application and performing updates. However, when multiple users login to application the update operation slow down, and updates are not reflected to UI if multiple updates are performed.

For example,

When single user login to application:

- User updated/changed 7 times and changes are reflected as expected.

When multiple user login:

- Out of 7 record change only 3 were reflected.
- And for second user out of 7 , 2 were reflected correctly.

After 10 minutes all changes appears in database for all 7 records. It means update statement on GTT has slowed down.

Please help me on this. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the problem is related to global temporary tables?  If you temporarily replace the GTT with a regular table, what happens to the performance?  Also, how many rows are being updated in that table?  Finally, it might help to investigate the `UPDATE` statements, and see how long they are taking and what they are waiting on.  I would recommend finding the statements in `V$SQL`, and then generating the SQL Monitor report with: `select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor(sql_id => 'enter SQL_ID here') from dual;`.  Paste the output to the question.

Comment: Have you created a separate temporary tablespace for your global temporary tables?

Comment: I can't use permanent table because I need to keep it session specific.if I use permanent table then it will not keep user specific data in session.for ex: if multiple user login at same time they permanent table can't show user specific data.

Comment: I don't have DBA privileges to create separate temporary table space...place gtt into temporary table space will help? Kindly suggest the workaround

Comment: Global Temporary Tables write to a temporary tablespace. If you do nothing specific they use the default TEMP tablespace. This means writing to and reading from GTTs can lead to I/O contention with other processes such as large sorts. Therefore it is good practice to create a dedicated tablespace for GTTs and explicitly assign it when you create the table. Not saying this would solve your case. But even the weediest database should be able to handle seven concurrent users, so if you're struggling you have some fundamental architectural problem. You need a DBA to help you diagnose and fix it.